# Python: Trying to split instream into bit sized chunks

Tags: python, binary, byte, bit

Currently I'm reading an instream and splicing it into 3 byte chunks:

```
instream_chunks = [instream[i:i+3]for i in range (0, len(instream), 3)]
```

What I'm failing to do is to split this instream into 22 bit sized chunks. Is there a way to do that in Python?

Edit: The instream is created (for test purposes) like this:

```
instream = open('C:/xxx/test.txt', 'rb+')
```

And this instream is then being used in this function

```
def write(self, instream: typ.BinaryIO):
```

Which starts with what I described above.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing `[instream[i:i+22]for i in range (0, len(instream), 22)]
`?

Comment: That would make the chunks 22 byte sized, whereas I would like them to be bit sized. To explain this a bit further: The read data is supposed to be split into 22-bit sized chunks so they can be written to specific fields in a binary stream.

Comment: If each element of instream is a byte, then you'll have to split the individual elements, for instance by converting instream from an iterable of bytes to one of bits.

Comment: The instream doesn't really have defined elements as it is a binary stream. It could be a textfile, user input or even a picture file. 

I'm currently trying to just read 22 bits from the instream, but the .read() function doesn't seem to have any specific bit functionality either.

Comment: Yes, but without knowing something about where you're getting this instream from I can't help you further. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added some information to the opening post about the creation of the instream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have enough memory, you can convert the instream to a list of bits and then slice it however you want.

```
def access_bit(data, num):
    base = int(num/8)
    shift = num % 8
    return (data[base] & (1<<shift)) >> shift

def to_bits(instream):
    ba = bytearray(instream.read())
    return [access_bit(ba,i) for i in range(len(ba)*8)]
```

`>>>to_bits(open('test.txt','rb'))`

`[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Otherwise you'll have to read smaller chunks in multiple of size you want, and then use the above method on each. For example, you read 22*4 = 88 bits, or 11 bytes, and then call to_bits on that, split the resulting array into 4 22bit chunks, and repeat.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.